# How to use multiple property files (via PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer), having one property file optional?

Tags: java, spring

In my applicationContext.xml file of my Spring project, I use a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer manage the external properties from two configuration files, like this:

```
  <!-- Configuration. -->
  <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
      <list>
        <value>file:${universign.configuration}</value>
        <value>file:${universign.common.configuration}</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

The two file paths in the list are provided by system properties. My question is: How can I make the second value optional? When I launch the program, some times I want to launch with 1 configuraiton file, sometimes 2. But using my configuration above, if I don't provide the two system properties, the program cannot be launched, it will give an Exception like this:

```
[WARNING] Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@12f9f896{/,[file:///opt/li/projects/universign/universign-admin-www/webapp/, file:///opt/li/projects/universign/universign-admin-www/target/tmp/universign-config-8_17-SNAPSHOT-universign-admin-www_zip1/],UNAVAILABLE}{file:///opt/li/projects/universign/universign-admin-www/webapp/}
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${universign.common.configuration} (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:89)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
...
```

How to make one of the two configuration files optional?

Comment: please try with <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>

Comment: @zpavel Thanks, it works, this, is exactly what I need.

Comment: cool. please upvote my comment.